# Use CPP enums constants in java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have been working on a project that supports both CPP and Java, I have a few enum constants in cpp header. Is it possible by any change to use those headers in java using JNI??

Comment: Why? I mean yes, probably. But just translate the values to Java. Write a small C++ program to do it if you think they might change, but it should be trivial to write that translator; JNI is complex. JNA is simpler, but you don't actually have a native method to call - you just want constants.

Comment: JNI is runtime. Named constants are compile-time, to be referenced by Java source code. So, no.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the integer value of the C++ `enum` into Java.  For example, C `errno` values (technically not an `enum`, but I grabbed this example from some code that I have handy).

Java:

```
public static final int EINVAL = getEINVAL();

private static final int getEINVAL();
```

Native code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_some_class_getEINVAL( JNIEnv *env, jclass cls )
{
    return( EINVAL );
}
```

Note that you should always use `javah` to generate the native header file, then use those declarations to define your native functions.

Feel free to replace Java `int` with `Integer` or even a Java `enum`.  I haven't tried this specific code:

```
enum errno
{
    EINVAL( getEINVAL() ),
    ENOENT( getENOENT() ),
       .
       .


    private int value;

    errno( int value )
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

but something similar should be easy to code.

Replacing native `errno` values with `enum` values is trivial for each value. The hard part becomes how to maintain the connection between Java and native values when there are many, many `enum` constants to pass to Java.  I've never found a clearer way than simply hardcoding the methods.  It can be tedious but it's manageable if the `enum` values don't change.  If the native `enum` values change a lot, you may have to come up with another method just so you don't spend a lot of time just replacing values in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) might be of help in this case. It takes header files, or annotated header files, and creates a C JNI and Java wrapper for declarations.

So, if you have

```
enum Values {
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
};
```

With

```
%module ValuesClass

%include "Values.h"
```

You can quickly get

```
public final class Values {
  public final static Values Value1 = new Values("Value1");
  public final static Values Value2 = new Values("Value2");
  public final static Values Value3 = new Values("Value3");

  public final int swigValue() {
    return swigValue;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return swigName;
  }

  public static Values swigToEnum(int swigValue) {
    if (swigValue < swigValues.length && swigValue >= 0 && swigValues[swigValue].swigValue == swigValue)
      return swigValues[swigValue];
    for (int i = 0; i < swigValues.length; i++)
      if (swigValues[i].swigValue == swigValue)
        return swigValues[i];
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No enum " + Values.class + " with value " + swigValue);
  }

  private Values(String swigName) {
    this.swigName = swigName;
    this.swigValue = swigNext++;
  }

  private Values(String swigName, int swigValue) {
    this.swigName = swigName;
    this.swigValue = swigValue;
    swigNext = swigValue+1;
  }

  private Values(String swigName, Values swigEnum) {
    this.swigName = swigName;
    this.swigValue = swigEnum.swigValue;
    swigNext = this.swigValue+1;
  }

  private static Values[] swigValues = { Value1, Value2, Value3 };
  private static int swigNext = 0;
  private final int swigValue;
  private final String swigName;
}
```

In this simple case, the Java code is all you need so it doesn't actually use JNI.